# SQL query to multiple objects using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm taking the time to learn EF (specifically version 6).

I created two tables in MSSQL and linked up EF6 to the database creating the EF model framework.

Then I created the classes in code.  My desire is to have one row pulled with a list of items for "UserDatas" (yes I know it's misspelled).

Consider this code:

```
public class user
{
    [Key]
    public int pkID;
    public string ForeignCode;
    public string UserName;
    public virtual List<UserData> UserDatas { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    [Key]
    public int pkID;
    public int fkUserID;
    public string ColumnName;
    public string ColumnValue;
}

class Program
{
    static TestData db = new TestData();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var record = db.tblUsers.Select(x => new { x.UserName, x.pkID }).FirstOrDefault();

        var record2 = db.tblUsers.Include(x => x.tblUserDatas).ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

The first query is just a test to pull the primary record in the tblUsers table.

The second query is where I am attempting to pull all fields related to that user which include things like first name, last name, address, etc...

What happens when I set a break point on the Console.Readline(), I see 5 rows listed for record2.  The "user" class is duplicated in each of those rows.  I was expecting to see that only listed once with a list of items for "UserDatas".

How can I get this query to come through as I expect with one row containing a list of "UserDatas"?

Again, this is only for learning purposes so don't worry about data and if this is the best way to store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as the following (if you don't need the projection/anonymous object) and assuming your entities are configured correctly

```
var user = db.tblUsers
             .Include(x => x.UserDatas) // include user data
             .FirstOrDefault(); // select the first user
```

Some notes,

1. There is no need to prefix tables with `tbl`
2. There is no need to prefix fields with `pk`, `fk`
3. If you used `Id`, you don't need to specify `[key]`

Comment: Ah, FirstorDefault().  This gets me close.  If I do a "record2." and scroll to look for UserDatas in the list I don't see it.  But I do see the data when I observe it in debug.  Am I linking the UserDatas correctly in the Users class object?

Comment: @DaBlue probably not, you'll have to either use standard naming of your navigation properties and ids or use attributes or fluent api to denote the relationships. Most tutorials will show how to do this

Comment: Thanks, Michael you helped a lot.  Removing the tbl on the tables fixed the ability to pick from the list on that object.

Comment: (The class name should match the table name)